# Inserting data into foreign key column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a user and group table. In user table I have id,name . In group table I have id group_name, created_by , user_id. Here a user can belong to more than one group but not the same group twice. A group can have many users but not the same user twice.

Here is my code.

## group.rb

```
module Client
  class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
  end
end
```

## user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client_groups
end
```

Now when a user creates a new group, he should be automatically be persisted into the user_id and created_by field.
So as per the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#why-associations-questionmark) , I tried to follow the same with my code like this

```
@user.Client::Group.new(client_group_params)
```

but it gave me an err.

So I tried another way,

```
def create
      @client_group = Client::Group.new(client_group_params)
      client_group_params[:created_by] = current_user.id
      client_group_params[:users_id] = current_user.id
      @client_group.save
      respond_with(@client_group)
    end

def client_group_params
      params.require(:client_group).permit(:group_name)
    end
```

It saved the group_name into the db but it did not save the created_by and the users_id field. Any idea?

I have made the user_id field foreign key.

Comment: Write like `belongs_to :client_groups, class_name: 'Client::Group'`, and `@user.build_client_groups(client_group_params)`

Comment: @ArupRakshit, I got this err `undefined method `Client' for nil:NilClass` . Here is the changes I have made `def create

      @client_group = @user.Client::Group.new(client_group_params)
      # client_group_params[:created_by] = current_user.id
      # client_group_params[:users_id] = current_user.id
      @client_group.save
      respond_with(@client_group)
    end`

Comment: read my comment again. And your are doing lot of wrong things, inside the `create` action.

Comment: @ArupRakshit , yes I am just getting started with rails so I do not have much idea. It would be really great if you can tell me what I am doing wrong. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to change the assoication declaration as below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client_group,
    class_name: 'Client::Group',
    foreign_key: :group_id
end
```

As per the association you have, the `User` model should have the column called `group_id`. Add it through migration. I am not seeing the point of adding the `user_id` to the `Group` model.

Then change the `create` action as :

```
def create
  @client_group = current_user.build_client_group(
    client_group_params.merge(created_by: current_user.id)
   )
  @client_group.save
  respond_with(@client_group)
end
```

Comment: I have again got an err `undefined method `build_client_groups' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @SushantBajracharya so, your `current_user` is `nil`. Are you using `Devise`? if not from where this method `current_user` is coming?

Comment: I printed this in the create method `render text: current_user.id` and I got back my id.

Comment: add the full error log to the post, and use my updated code. When `current_user` is `nil`, how you got the `id` don't know. But please show the error stack from rails log.

Comment: Now I have got an err like this `undefined method `build_client_group' for #<FormUser:0x10f85128>` . I checked development.log inside the root/log of my app and it was empty

Comment: the logs are flowing in the shell, where you ran `rails s`.. please look there.. Where you defined `FormUser` class ?

Comment: Processing by Client::GroupsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TWmWvLnsooBdbWjEhQoRF+DnDfMyKWvnq+oWp1m6MM+i1yoJPX9ja9B1p/pmr9Hc1rT0yiNB4NIhwhSh==", "client_group"=>{"group_name"=>"asdfasdfasdf"}, "commit"=>"Create Group"}
  FormUser Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
NoMethodError (undefined method `build_client_group' for #<FormUser:0x10f85128>):
  app/controllers/client/groups_controller.rb:22:in `create'

Comment: That is what I have got in my terminal.

Comment: @RichPeck He fixed it.. We talked over chat.. :)